# How do I view pictures while in Jasper Server report in html format?

Tags: java, jasper-reports, jasperserver

> I'm using Jasper Server. Ip: `http://app2:8080/jasperserver/`
>   Application - Ip: `http://app1:4545/gui/`

When I get a picture of my Jasper reports using Application Server,
If the image is displayed pdf, html unable to view the images.

How can I make the display of images in html reports?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On report right click and Properties > +More under the Properties > Add this parameters;
**net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics = false**
and on Jasper Server :

jasperreports-server-cp-5.0.0/apache-tomcat/webapps/jasperserver/WEB-INF/classes/jasperreports.properties
add this parameter;
**net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.graphics = false**

Answer (score 0):

1 - You can using a simply URL File Path. Create one image component.

2 - You can active "Markup" for show HTML interpreted.

3 - You can use itext API, to generate PDF using HTML code.

maybe exists another options.